# Need script to continue when switching over to new user

Tags: shell, unix, su

SO I have this script that will ssh you onto a new system, switch into a new user, and then I need it to execute three more commands while under that user. This is how I have it setup right now.

```
ssh -t $7 'cd /home/install/ ; su -c bash install ; tar -xvf [tarball] ; cd [directory] ; ./execute install ; bash'
```

What it will do is switch my user to the install user, but once there it doesn't execute any of the following commands. Only after I exit out of the install and back into the root user will those final commands run.

So for a tldr; I need a way to run those last three commands as the install user.

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:
1. Your quotes are getting interpreted away
2. You're not using `su` correctly

If you want `su` to execute commands as that user, you have to provide them in STDIN, e.g. `echo 'cd; ls' | su user`. However, to do that, you're going to need to escape some stuff.

If the command you want to run as the user *install* is:

```
cmd1; cmd2; cmd3
```

Therefore, you provide it to `su` like so:

```
echo 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3' | su install
```

However, you also want to execute it over ssh, which means you have to escape the quotes in the first sequence:

```
ssh user@host 'echo \'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3\' | su install'
```

Comment: Well I tried your advice and it didn't exactly perform as expected. What I did realize however is what it is that is happening. I need job control access when I switch to the install user. This is the error I get from bash once I switch users "bash: no job control in this shell".

Comment: What I mean by not perform as expected, is that it logged me in but as a completely different user than if I were to issue the command 'su -c bash install'.

Comment: And I cannot connect through "ssh install@host" or "sudo ssh install@host" as the permissions around this are denied.

Comment: I can't help you deal with the ssh issue; that's on your server setup. As for `su`, you need to remove the `-c bash`. Su is taking its commands from STDIN, not from the -c. You could instead do `ssh user@host 'su install -c \'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3\''`

Comment: After finagling around a bit I was able to get your above advice to work. I used a different setup than you suggested, but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` instead of `su`, that is what you need really.